# Zii Widgets on Yii - Version of JqueryUI

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, yii, yii-extensions

I just recently started playing around with the Yii Framework. I am confused by the Zii Widgets however. I know that the Zii widgets use jquery UI for their functionality. 
Looking through the files, i found that jquery ui 1.9.2 is included with the framework.
Due to the recent major changes in jquery ui as a whole, I was wondering if I use the latest version of jquery UI, will that break the zii widget functionality. Is there anyway to use Zii widgets with jquery ui 1.10 and somehow disable the default jquery ui that comes with the framework?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its too broad question, it depends on the changes in the Jquery UI widgets, some Zii widgets may work, some others may not. if you don't **require** the latest version of Jquery UI and want to use the Zii widgets, then stick with the included version and deal with it.

Comment: What exactly are the advantages of using Zii Widgets over using jquery ui by themselves? I read somewhere that it helps with data sorting and listing when data is accessed through ActiveRecord. But im not sure how it works since Im still new to the framework.

Comment: By using the zii widgets you don't have to care about jquery ui, you just call the widget from PHP and it will render the widget using your application data, models and stuff. not all widgets are based on jquery ui, you have grid with out-of-the-box ajax pagination, search and sorting. you can always do all of this by hand, but yii tries to help you do things much easier, faster and better.